# MVC3 My program is looking in the wrong location for the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a project and in it worked hard and created many models, views and controllers. All worked great. I decided to rename one of my models, and accordingly rename my controller and view thinking it would all continue to work great. This is because I wanted to use the origional name for something more appriopriate later. For example.

**Old Names:**
MyOldModel
MyOldController
MyOldView

**Were renamed to:**
MyNewModel
MyNewController
MyNewView

Now all still works great execpt that when I click the link to my new view my program looks for and tries to show MyOldView which obviously does not exist. However when I manually put in /MyNewView it works.

How do I change my controller to look for the Index in the MyNewView folder instead of looking for the Index in the MyOldView folder.

I even tried deleting and recreating the controller to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: To those who have been kind enough to reply so quickly something to note:
The exact steps taken were:
1. Rename the model file from MyOldModel.cs to MyNewModel.cs
2. Rename the controller file from MyOldController.cs to MyNewController.cs
3. Renamed the FOLDER on the view (which only contains Index.cshtml)
    from MyOldView to MyNewView
4. At each step visual studio prompted me to rename all refrences to the object being renamed and I accepted (said yes). So the class names all got updated correctly. From what I can see at least, so did all the other refrences.

According to what is being said here, it should be working.

I simply renamed the

Comment: where is your view located ( what folder ? ) . You should create a folder with the controller's name: (ex if your controller is named fooController , create a folder named foo ) and create your view there

Comment: check that your _Layout points to the right views also from button clicks

Comment: Post your controller class please, did you change any action names as well?

Comment: The folder (for the view) was renamed, both the controller class and the folder only contained the default Index and index.cshtml. The _Layout has no links in it anymore as they were not needed. I am using a partial view to load the links from a different file. Put this as an answer and I will give you the accepted answer points as it was the links in the other file that were wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @RhysW Please put your comment as an answer. It has led me to the solution and I would like to give you the accepted answer points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the op, my comment as an answer:

check that your _Layout points to the right views also from button clicks otherwise it will still be searching for the old controllers/views when you have replaced/renamed them with the new controllers/views, glad to be of assistance!

Comment: I have an XML file of the links and other bits of information to small to warrent a proper table. One of my models reads this in and parses it. Then the links are displayed in the partial view which in turn is displayed as part of the _Layout.cshtml. This is how your comment led me to the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah partial views, i forgot about those and shot straight for the biggun, glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that you renamed the class inside the Controller file, not just the file itself?  i.e. so it contains

```
public class MyNewController : Controller {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I understand this and was careful to ensure all refrences got renamed. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have an Index action on the `MyNewController`:

```
public class MyNewController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now make sure that you have placed the view in `~/Views/MyNew/Index.cshtml`. That's the established convention. Notice that if your controller class is called `MyNewController`, the folder must be called `MyNew`. Also don't forget to recompile your web application after renaming the controller class.

Comment: I understand this and was careful to ensure all refrences got renamed. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the required modifications to your routes list (registered in Global.asax file i Application_Start() event):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I looked there and did not see anything that can help.